# Why thrust force is acting in horizontal direction?

Tags: momentum

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgyxD.png)

As you can see, there's a force acting on the body in backward direction. But I can't understand where it is coming from. As mass is added from the ceiling (upward direction), why there's force in the vertical direction. It has to do something with change in momentum?
Also, $v_{r}$ (relative velocity) is considered as v. But why? Shouldn't it be zero(0)?!

Answer (score 1):

Initially the sand has a horizontal velocity of zero and a downward vertical velocity.
The vertical velocity of the sand is changed to zero by an upward vertical force on the sand due to the car.
As the sand which is falling into the car hits the sand in the car it has a horizontal force on it in the forward direction due to the sand in the car (and the car) which accelerates the falling sand in the forward direction.
The Newton third law reaction to the force on the falling sand due to the sand in the car (and the car) is an equal and opposite force on the sand in the car (and the car) due to the falling sand.
That is the backward force on the car (and the sand inside it).
The initial horizontal velocity of the falling sand is zero and the final horizontal velocity of the falling sand which ends up in the car is the velocity of the car.